# How to generate two heatmap on same scale?

Tags: highcharts, merge, series

Following code generate the heatmaps side by side.

```
<html>
<head>
    <script type='text/javascript' src='http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.js'></script>
    <script src="http://code.highcharts.com/stock/highstock.js"></script>
        <script src="http://code.highcharts.com/modules/heatmap.js"></script>
    <script>

   $(document).ready(function() {

    var options = {
        chart: {
            renderTo: 'container1',
            type: 'heatmap',
            zoomType:'x',
            plotWidth:400,
            plotHeight:400
        },
          title: {
            text: 'HeatMap1'
        },

        xAxis: {
            categories: ['11230', '11231', '11232', '11233', '11234', '11235']
        },

        yAxis: {
            categories: ['11230', '11231', '11232', '11233', '11234', '11235'],
            title: null
        },

        colorAxis: {
            min: 0,
            minColor: '#FFFFFF',
            maxColor: Highcharts.getOptions().colors[0]
        },

        legend: {
            align: 'right',
            layout: 'vertical',
            margin: 0,
            verticalAlign: 'top',
            y: 25,
            symbolHeight: 280
        },
        plotOptions:{
                   series:{
                          turboThreshold: 0
                          }
        },
        series: [{}]
    };

    $.getJSON('sample1.json', function(data) {
        options.series[0].data = data;
        var chart = new Highcharts.Chart(options);
    });

});

   $(document).ready(function() {

    var options = {
        chart: {
            renderTo: 'container2',
            type: 'heatmap',
            zoomType:'x',
            plotWidth:400,
            plotHeight:400
        },
          title: {
            text: 'HeatMap2'
        },

        xAxis: {
            categories: ['11230', '11231', '11232', '11233', '11234', '11235']
        },

        yAxis: {
            categories: ['11230', '11231', '11232', '11233', '11234', '11235'],
            title: null
        },

        colorAxis: {
            min: 0,
            minColor: '#FFFFFF',
            maxColor: Highcharts.getOptions().colors[0]
        },

        legend: {
            align: 'right',
            layout: 'vertical',
            margin: 0,
            verticalAlign: 'top',
            y: 25,
            symbolHeight: 280
        },
        plotOptions:{
                   series:{
                          turboThreshold: 0
                          }
        },
        series: [{}]
    };

    $.getJSON('sample2.json', function(data) {
        options.series[0].data = data;
        var chart = new Highcharts.Chart(options);
    });

});

    </script>
</head>
<body>
<table>
<tr>
<td><div id="container1" style="width: 300px; height: 300px; margin: 0 auto"></div></td>
<td><div id="container2" style="width: 300px; height: 300px; margin: 0 auto"></div></td>
</tr>
</table>
</body>
</html>
```

But how can i merge two heat map into one plot sharing same x-axis.
[image]

Comment: Could you add a picture or sketch how you would combine them?

Comment: Please post your mockup.

Answer (score 1):

Try doing  multiple y axis in same pane like this

```
  yAxis: [
                  {
                    opposite : false,             

                    title: {
                        text: 'HeatMap1'
                    },
                    top: 0

                },{
                    opposite : false, 
                    title: {
                        text: 'HeatMap2'
                    },
                    top: 30

                }]
```